# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. AES Decryption

Tags: java, exception, encryption, cryptography, udp

Implement UDP chat application using symmetric AES encryption. I start with the client side having a message and sending the message encrypted (ciphertext) to the server side. Then the server side will decrypt with the fixed key and the ciphertext to get the original message. Both the server-side and client-side will use this key for encrypting and decrypt

```
client.sentThenReceive(" P@ssword123@@24".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

```
server.receiveThenSend(" P@ssword123@@24".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Everything worked properly until I try to decrypt method on the server side with the ciphertext and given the key  causing the error below in this line of code

```
byte[] originalMessage = cipher.doFinal(message);
```

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:858)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:938)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:734)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:434)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2206)
    at Server.Decryption(Server.java:45)
    at Server.receiveThenSend(Server.java:63)
    at Server.main(Server.java:81)
```

Here is the encryption method in the client side, after the client encrypte the message and send it to the client side

```
public byte[] Encryption(byte[] message, byte[] keyBytes)throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    // Step 5: Create a Cipher object
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKey secrekey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    cipher.init(cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secrekey);
    byte[] Encryption = cipher.doFinal(message);
    return Encryption;
}
```

When the Server side receive the encrypted message from the client side, it will using decrypte method to decrypt. The error evoke by this line of code:  byte[] originalMessage = cipher.doFinal(message);

```
public String Decryption(byte[] message, byte[] keyBytes)throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        cipher.init(cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] originalMessage = cipher.doFinal(message);
        return new String(originalMessage);
}
```

This is the send method in client side use to send the ciphertext to server side

```
public void sentThenReceive(byte[] key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        try {
            String messageToSend = scanner.nextLine();
            byte[] message = messageToSend.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket (message, message.length, inetAddress, 2468);
            datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);
```

This is the receive method in the server side use to receive the message from client side

```
public void receiveThenSend(byte[] key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    while (true) {
        try {
            DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            datagramSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
            System.out.println(Decryption(datagramPacket.getData(),key));
            InetAddress inetAddress = datagramPacket.getAddress();
            int port = datagramPacket.getPort();
            datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, inetAddress, port);
            datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);
```

I'm a learner so anyone please feel free to teach me what wrong with my code and how I can fix it. I would very appreciate your input!

Comment: You are trying to do too many things at the same time. Right now you don't know if your error is in the communication or in your encryption logic. First, verify that your encryption works without the communication - can you decrypt what you encrypt ? Secondly, verify that you can communicate without  encryption... After this, THEN you are ready to communicate and encrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two general causes of a Bad Padding exception, either different modes set or failed decryption.

First check that you have explicitly set the padding mode the same on both sides.

If not that, then you need to check that the whole decryption has not failed, resulting in garbage instead of well formed padding. Temporarily set the decryption side to "NoPadding" and see what the result is. Complete garbage means you have a more general decryption failure. A mostly good decryption, with some extra bytes at the end is a good decryption with added padding. You need to set the decryption side to expect that type of padding. Do not leave "NoPadding" set as it is less secure.

Comment: After I change the AES to AES/ECB/NoPadding in Decrypted method. It finally decrypted the ciphertext successfully but I want to ask how can I remove the extra output. here is the example of the output hi?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM

Comment: Both ECB and NoPadding are insecure, you should probably change them. From what you post I cannot see what is the "extra" output and what is the original plaintext. All 'NoPadding' does is to switch off the Bad Padding Exception, which lets you see the detail of the output. It does not fix the problem.

Comment: Actually, It fixes my decryption problem, I was able to decrypt the ciphertext and able to view the original message with an extra output chunk. The "hi" words are the original message you can see it right at the beginning and the symbols and letters after it is the extra chunk. Output:  hi?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM?8G?Y???&?t??vM

Comment: The 'extra chunk' is the padding. You need to identify the form of [cryptographic padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) that is being used, and set your decryption side to expect that type of padding. Then it will be removed automatically.

Comment: The same algorithm being use for both encryption and decryption is AES/ECB/NoPadding, so there technically no padding right ?

Comment: Correct, but NoPadding is not as secure as, say, PKCS7 padding. Neither is ECB mode secure, see the [Linux Penguin image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_(ECB)) for why. Better to use either CBC or CTR mode. CTR mode does not need padding.

Comment: Yes I  know it is not secure, but my deadline is coming so I use as temporarily. I know what happen I use this Cipher.getInstance("AES"); in the client encryption, and I use this Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding") in the server decryption. So conclude the extra chunk is the AES padding, But I don't know how to remove that padding

Comment: Set the padding to be the same on both sides, PKCS7 unless you have a reason to use something else. If it is set the same on both sides, then it will be added and removed automatically.

Comment: I got this error Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting AES/ECB/PKCS7

Comment: Sometimes PKCS7 is called PKCS5, for historical reasons. Have a look through the documentation to see which padding types are supported.

Comment: I have tried that many times and got this error Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting AES/ECB/PKCS5.  That's why I use no padding as a temporary solution but the output still has a chunk of AES padding from the Encryption

Comment: Read the documentation to see what paddings are supported.